# Use Color in Text() the right way

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, colors

How do I show my Color data in Text() view the right way? I tried 3 methods but not work for all.

Error = Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Color' conform to 'StringProtocol'

```
var body: some View {
    Text("\(colorΩ)")
    Text(String(colorΩ))
    Text(colorΩ)   
}
```

Comment: How do you want to show it?

Comment: Hi OG.  let colorΩ = Color.white. I am reading color from my background I want to display this "Color.White" or ".white"

Comment: `SwiftUI.Color` is a `View` there is nothing to show. `UIColor`, `CGColor` have variables to show but not `Color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is not clear but a possible variant is

```
Text(String(describing: colorΩ))
```

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

[image: demo]

Comment: OG you saved my 4 hours of researching

Comment: @StevenBlue: 4 hours! You could make a custom enum or custom description in 4 min in case if you did not know about apple free api, do not forget current answer cannot return a human understandable color name for all possible colors!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in another way similar to @Asperi answer:

```
Text(colorΩ.description)
```